# After I add option autoplay of youtube ,I can't see the ads

Tags: youtube-api, ads, autoplay

When I write youtube iframe tag with autoplay like this,

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T_gCnf9-qW0?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can see the ad while video playing but, when

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T_gCnf9-qW0?showinfo=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can't see the ads. i just added autoplay=1.

How can I see the ads with autoplay ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error with your code. You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors) which shows how to set `autoplay` properly. Also be noted that in certain mobile browsers (such as Chrome and Safari), the HTML5  element only allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a user interaction (such as tapping on the player). As stated in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations), functions and parameters such as `autoplay`, `playVideo()`, `loadVideoById()` won't work in all mobile environments due to this restriction.